# debug toolbar broken after symfony 6 upgrade, calling inexistant authenticationManagerEnabled property

Tags: php, symfony

After upgrading from symfony 5.4 to 6.0, the debug toolbar does not load and triggers this error :

> Neither the property "authenticatorManagerEnabled" nor one of the methods "authenticatorManagerEnabled()", "getauthenticatorManagerEnabled()"/"isauthenticatorManagerEnabled()"/"hasauthenticatorManagerEnabled()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DataCollector\SecurityDataCollector".

I understand the code enabling the new authenticator manager has been dropped in symfony 6, since it is now the only authentication system. But I have checked, I don't call that anywhere in my code.

(clarification: I am using the new security system).

My first guesses:

- cache, but I have cleared the cache
- outdated packages, but `composer outdated` seems fairly clean ( only 3 packages not related to symfony ).
- Looking at the error stack trace, but even that way I don't see where it's coming from.

At this point, I am not sure where to look.

Comment: "I have cleared the cache" did you manually delete the directory and start over? Doing a simple `bin/console cache:clear` isn't always enough.

Comment: Just guessing but does your 5.4 project have `enable_authenticator_manager: true` in `config/packages/security.yaml?  If not then you will have to make adjustments before moving to 6.0.

Comment: @Cerad yes it does. I did move to the new security system, which is why I was puzzled.

Comment: @craigh Great call, that did the trick ! I don't know if it's because of my setup, but `bin/console cache:clear` wasn't enough for me. I had to `rm -r var/cache/*`. Works now !

Answer (score 2):

Answer given by @craigh in the comments :

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

wasn't enough for me. I had to

```
rm -r var/cache/*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.global_clearer
```

Works for me when a simple cache:clear is not enough -
[Symfony Docs about the cache](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html)

[Screen shot from the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvh8g.png)